# TypeScript does not correctly infer type?

Tags: javascript, typescript, object, tsc

## Problem description

I want to have a function with generic return type which iterates through given object and do some operations with each of object values.

## Example

I have a function:

```
function clearObject<T extends object>(obj: T): T {
    const newInstance = { ...obj };
    const keys = Object.keys(newInstance);
    keys.forEach(key => {
        if (typeof newInstance[key as keyof object] === 'function') {
            return;
        }

        if (typeof newInstance[key as keyof object] === 'object') {
            newInstance[key as keyof object] = clearObject<object>(newInstance[key as keyof object]);
        }
    });
    return obj;
}
```

On the line:

```
newInstance[key as keyof object] = clearObject<object>(newInstance[key as keyof object]);
```

TS detects an error:

> TS2322: Type 'object' is not assignable to type 'never'.

Why? In above condition, I am verifying that `newInstance[key]` is of type *'object'*. Is this issue of TypeScript? I am using the newest release, 4.9.

Comment: I tried `let temp = newInstance[key as keyof object] ` followed by `// ^?` on the next line, and found that it is considered `never` even earlier, even before the `if` statements. Further testing seems to show that the base type of an object is `{}`, and since this has no safe keys, `type test = {}[string]` is invalid, and `type test = {} [keyof {}]` is same as never.

Comment: @qrsngky I also tried to make T extend Record<any, any>, when should be your above concern about safe keys considered resolved, but it also ends with similiar error.

Comment: @jakob_frankovic If that's the only change, then since `keyof object` has no guaranteed values anyway, you still can't have `something[key as keyof object]`. Using `let test: keyof object;` followed by `// ^?` Tells me that the inferred type is `let test: never`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These sorts of recursive "rebuilds" of an object are very hard to get right while also keeping the type-system happy. Sometimes casts are inevitable.

Rather than having to decide whether it is safe to recursively call your function, it's probably better to allow the function to accept any type and then to deal with it appropriately. As such:

```js
function clearObject<T>(obj: T): T {
    switch (typeof obj) {
        case "object":
            {
                // null is an object
                if (obj == null) {
                    return obj;
                }
                // arrays are objects
                if (Array.isArray(obj)) {
                    return obj.map(clearObject) as T
                }
                // "normal" objects
                return Object.fromEntries(
                    Object.entries(obj).map(([k, v]) => [k, clearObject(v)])
                ) as T
            }
        default: {
            return obj;
        }
    }
}
```

should provide a nice way to recurse through whatever is passed.

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=6#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBANgUwIYCcDyAjAKzWgB4AVAPgAo5CAuRMgSgbMQG8BYAKET8QDOAdxhQIAC0RUoATwAOaOMES0CTDj35bkGAWkQAiVcSgG6m7Za69LtvgHp7iMCBQpEMAYgxJj0C3aWMMo0hIgAvOHOrijq1oEJiFhoUCBYvoQA3AGJfAC+ObmO3lhYGDJe2Pp+UAKFicFSAIKl5QB0ni1lMqFqcfW5fMmp6SqEbQC2GHJUqJi4hCbquowDgQU2g4jFBmBwWFMoBmNE0HWbg8NpSPinUG3AWHATAKJgUFgwaAJUa7m3JjaaHen2+vSYk2mVCoAG0ANYAGkQADcALrqcIURDwpFzbAA6BUZFMdF-WzLLxkMn5NYAEzQwAwrigDHiiSuo1U2QuWg2vJ4Gx4EAQAig3giHG8rKlkowDAM4jQbjgxzySLwDBh7GQDAAjIg1YhdQAmADMqINBp4xX4AD0APw8IUisV4CV4hZ3KgYJjWpx2x3cZ1gARwdBtFBwADmVDwTCAA)

Comment: That is great approach and working properly. Thank you.